# Kafka to HDFS sync with data transformation

Tags: hdfs, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to kafka, we have following requirement:

> 1) Do a daily sync of data from Kafka to HDFS, partitioned by specific key in the JSON payload stored in Kafka clusters.
>   2) JSON payload is required to be broken into two different files

Wondering if this can be achieved using HDFS kafka connector ? Saw some documentation, I think I can get #1 working easily but unable to understand if there is any thing out of the box for my second requirement.
Any suggestion on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at message transforms and see if they for your use case https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms. Basically I'm envisioning 2 different hdfs connector instances reading from the same topic and using someone like ExtractField to pull what you want out of the payload for each instance and then writing to two different hdfs locations.

Comment: Wow why I never thought in that direction...Not sure if that will work and address my requirements but at-least this gave me a way to try !!!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at message transforms and see if they for your use case https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms. Basically I'm envisioning 2 different hdfs connector instances reading from the same topic and using someone like ExtractField to pull what you want out of the payload for each instance and then writing to two different hdfs locations.